# Firefox and Safari will not download files from my server only

Tags: css, apache, firefox, configuration, download

I've been working for a client the past couple of weeks, and I'm absolutely certain that the code I've written has been working fine cross-browser. However, as of yesterday the site has not been downloading content from my server when viewing through Firefox or Safari (to make things even weirder the site loads fine in Chrome / IE).

## Update

When I view the site from a proxy, the CSS file listed below loads fine. Now this is getting weird ...

## Errors?

Well, as I'm sure many of you would have done I quickly went to validate the HTML and CSS of the pages, wondering if that was causing this issue. But then I ran a test that quite frankly made any validation error unrelated: I tried loading a one-line `CSS` file directly in my browser.

[The link to this CSS file is here](http://deliberti.it/test/css/test.css)

As @Ralph asked below, *What is the purpose of supplying us with a CSS file?*. The purpose of supplying you with the CSS file is to demonstrate how this one-line CSS file downloads fine in Chrome/IE but not in Firefox/Safari and I cannot understand why that might be.

I do not have control over the server but my client does, and is quite familiar with it. He is currently away so I'm unable to ask him if he's made changes as of 24 hours ago, but I'd like to determine this myself if possible.

**Question:**

Is there any server configuration that any of you know of that would cause Firefox and Safari to *not* download both CSS and JS files? I've emptied out the `.htaccess` file to be sure the error wasn't coming from there.

## Notes / attempts I've made

- Firefox *is* retrieving the file (according to firebug, which returns an OK GET Request
- The header is `text/css` as it should be (view the CSS link above and do *right click* -> *page Info*
- This is an Apache 2.2 server
- In Firefox, I've tried to completely re-download the page by doing *Control + Shift + R* but still, no content is downloaded.

I'm happy to supply any other information as requested.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Are you able to post a link to the site? I'm not sure what the point of your CSS file link is.

Comment: @ralph.m The point of the CSS file is to show that the file opens fine in Chrome, IE, but not in Firefox / Safari. The problem isn't the site but the fact that the external files are not being downloaded

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the clarification. It's weird that FF downloads the files but can't read/display them.

Comment: @ralph.m I'm glad you see where I'm coming from now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using Gzip compression and FireFox / Safari were not working because of it. Removing the compression fixed the problem.

```
<filesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
Header set Content-Encoding x-deflate
# Header set Content-Encoding compress
# Header set Content-Encoding x-gzip
</filesMatch>
```

Comment: Hehe, I wondered about that. Interesting. I guess that begs the question of why Gzip wasn't working.

Comment: @ralph.m See the update, these are the lines that caused the errors. Any ideas why?